# Django reporting 404 error on simple view?

Tags: python, django, url, view

I'm just barely getting started with Python and Django.

I've created my modules, migrated, added my modules to the admin section, etc. Now, I need to create my first view. I've been following [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) (Yes the machine I'm on is running 1.6)

My views.py file in the app (setup) looks like this...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Setup Index")
```

My app'a urls.py looks like this...

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from setup import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

And my root urls.py looks like this...

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from django.contrib import admin as djangoAdmin
from admin.controller import ReportWizard
from admin.forms import reportDetailsForm, reportDataViewsForm
from setup import views
djangoAdmin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^django-admin/', include(djangoAdmin.site.urls)),
    #New User Wizard URL
    url(r'^setup/', include('setup.urls')),
)
```

As far as I can tell I have followed the guide to the letter, but I am recieving a 404 error when navigating to myIP/setup.

There are no error messages on the 404 page. What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Does the admin work?

Comment: The admin works perfectly.

Comment: What does the 404 page look like? Is it the standard yellow Django error page?

Comment: Yes. It is the standard Django 404 page.

Comment: Can you post the 404 Error page?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the 404 page.

Comment: `/setup` and `/setup/` are not the same URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your settings seem to override the default for either [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#append-slash) or [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#middleware-classes).

Opening `http://example.com/setup` should cause a redirect to `http://example.com/setup/`, but somehow it doesn't for you.

Note that the latter URL is matched by your `urls.py` while the former is not (as should be the case).

The above should work if 'CommonMiddleWare`is enabled and`APPEND_SLASH`is set to`True`.